# React - Passing complex object variable to React Component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, components

I'm still learning and I may be thing of this wrong.

I have created a class that essentially acts as a small database with functions to create, delete, and modify the data.

I import this class and define a variable for it in a React Component.  That component creates an interactive table with buttons and all the necessary input elements.  This is all working great and my table updates, deletes, and changes as expected.

The react component I just described is a modal dialog box and I need to be able to pass that "small database" class variable into and back out of the react component.

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks,
William

EDIT:  Adding code that is partially working....

```js
interface Iprops {
  data: dataElement[];
  setParentData: (x: dataElement[]) => void;
}

export default class MSetup extends React.Component <Iprops, Istate>{

  data: dataStructure;

  constructor(props: Iprops) {
    super(props);
    this.data = new dataStructure(props.data);
  }
    
  handleChange(i: number, event: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) {
    this. data.setData(i, event.target.value);
    this.props.setParentLayers(this.data.dataVariable);
  {
}
```

```js
export class ParentLevel {
    public data: dataStructure;
    
    constructor(options: DialogConstructorOptions, initialState: dataElement[]) {
        this.reactRoot = React.createElement(LayerSetup, { data: initialState, setData: (x: dataElement[]) => this.setData(x)});
        this.target = options.element;
        ReactDOM.render(this.reactRoot, this.target);
    }
    
    setData(returnData: dataElement[]){
    // ***** THIS IS NEVER CALLED WHEN DATA CHANGES
        this.data = returnData;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your instance can absolutely be passed as a prop. There's no size limit; a variable is just a reference to a place in memory. Also, my recommendation would be to simply try stuff (especially before posting here ;) Beginners tend to misjudge what's possible and what isn't, so don't be afraid to just write code and see what happens.

Comment: Thanks, Chris.  I'll give it a shot.  I've been looking for a similar example and tried a few things that left me a little frustrated.  Do you happen to know of a good example that shows passing information from a parent to a child and then from the child to the parent?

Comment: Passing info down to a child is done using props. Like `<Child data={data} />`. To "send something back", you pass a setter function down: `setX={x => this.setX(x)}`. You can now call `props.setX(...)` from the child. You might also want to look into the [Context API](https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html).

Comment: Chris,  what about when using React.createElement?  With the line "let test = React.createElement(LayerSetup, { data: initialState });", I get the error: Argument of type '{ data: object; }' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Attributes & Iprops'.   Where initialState is of type object.

Comment: Okay... ignore that... I've made a bit more progress.  TypeScript can be a pain.  I have to define my props in the class as well.  Working through the bugs.

Comment: Yeah, I don't use TypeScript. Got this to work: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-silence-s6dql?file=/src/App.tsx

Comment: Sorry... Stuck with typescript.  I'm working inside the framework of an app that I'm expanding functionality on.    I added some simple code blocks.  I cannot get the setter function to be called.  I didn't add the code for the "dataStructure" class, but the important parts of what I'm trying to do is there.  Can you tell what I'm doing wrong?